# Nextjs requests on routing /_next/data/:bundleId/:path.json?*=:path - it is possible to remove * query params?

Tags: express, next.js

In project for client my team uses NextJS 12. When there are redirection between routes, we use nextjs/link component, so we are using NextJS Routing. When there is a route change on server side there is a GET visible as:

`/_next/data/:bundleId/:path.json?*=:path`

for example:

`/_next/data/sampleBuildId/test1/test2.json?*=test1&*=test2`

The client's security department said, that it is not allowed, and we should remove * query params. They argued that * sign is not compatible with RFC standard.

My goal is to remove this query, or at least remove * query parameters.

[visible in browser hits into *.json?*=...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYVBY.png)

I figured out that when you ask browser for GET `/_next/data/sampleBuildId/test1/test2.json` it is the same output as `/_next/data/sampleBuildId/test1/test2.json?*=test1&*=test2` ( it is the json like {"pageProps":{"data": .... )

I've tried to make nextjs or express to do request

`/_next/data/sampleBuildId/test1/test2.json`

instead of

`/_next/data/sampleBuildId/test1/test2.json?*=test1&*=test2`

It is even possible to do this? Why NextJS even add those * query parameters?

This is my index.js (path in project: <project_name>/server/index.js):

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const morgan = require('morgan');
var request = require('request');

const port = 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  // Logger
  server.use(morgan('tiny'));

  // NextJS
   server.all('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log('RETURNED IN server.all', req.url);
    return handle(req, res);
   });

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(
      `>>> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`
    );
  });
});
```

I've tried to do something like:

```
  server.use('/_next/data/:buildId/:path*/*.json', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req?.url?.indexOf('.json?*')) {
      console.log('TRY TO REWRITE IN server.use');
      const changed = req.url.split('?')[0];
      req.url = changed;

      // tried to change different places where url with .json?*= occurs
      req.originalUrl = changed;       
      req._parsedUrl.path = changed;
      req._parsedUrl.href = changed;
      req._parsedUrl._raw = changed;
      req.__NEXT_INIT_URL = changed;
      next();
    }
  });
```

before `server.all` and I see on console that in server.all there was changed url - without query params *. However in browser in network card, there was still request with * query params:

[result of first try - visible cutten string at console, but no expected results in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qusCQ.png)

I've also tried to use `return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(...))` from https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#conditional-statements , but I had error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'" at `export { NextRequest } from 'next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/request'`

So, is any of you done something like that, or it is even possible to rewrite url with .json?* ? I know that if I change nextjs/link component to , the request disappears, but it is not an option.

Thank you in advance